# FaceTime Video Calls on multiple devices

Tags: icloud, apple-id, facetime

I want to receive Facetime video calls on my MacBook Air and my iPhone at the same.  They are on the same apple id and I have it set up on my phone to use multiple devices and I cannot get it to work.

Is this setup possible?

Comment: Do you want to connect to and speak on multiple calls at the same time using your devices, or have both your devices ring for you to answer on one of them?

Answer (score 1):

FaceTime audio and video route to one device by design. You would need to add a second account on the second device to get two seats at a FaceTime meeting with your two devices.